# Как подключить директорию вне каталога cmake?

Tags: c, cmake

Потребовалось вынести из проекта поддиреткорию, которая указывалась с помощью add_subdirectory,
теперь cmake выдает ошибку

```
CMake Error at unit_tests/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source
  directory "/home/anton/dev/techno_park/cpp/task2/googletest" is not a
  subdirectory of
  "/home/anton/dev/techno_park/cpp/task2/filemetrics/unit_tests".  When
  specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly
  specified.
```

Как подключить директрию, не являющуюся подкаталогом ?
cmake файл

```
project(unit_tests)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../googletest)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})
add_executable(Google_Tests_run str_tests.cpp str_map_tests.cpp vec_tests.cpp
        tf_idf_priority_queue_tests.cpp file_metric_tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run gtest gtest_main)
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции `add_subdirectory(source_dir binary_dir)` можно указать абсолютный путь до директории или относительно директории исходников `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../sub_dir`. При указании абсолютного пути поддиректории также нужно указывать абсолютный путь для директории сборки.

Но делая такие включения Вы теряете возможность перемешать проект без необходимости делать исправления в конфигурационном файле

Comment: Такая ошибка при относительном пути(относительное директории) и и тоже самое при абсолютном
CMake Error at unit_tests/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source
  directory "/home/anton/dev/techno_park/cpp/task2/googletest" is not a
  subdirectory of
  "/home/anton/dev/techno_park/cpp/task2/filemetrics/unit_tests".  When
  specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly
  specified.

Comment: Пишет что нужно явно указать двоичный каталог, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Каталог для бинарных файлов указывается вторым аргументам. Однако CMake не рассчитан на работу с горизонтально организованными проектами. Так что скорее всего придется указывать бинарную директорию, отличную от той, в которой подключаемый проект собирался бы отдельно. Хотя это из-за этого файлы будут собираться повторно, однако такой вариант позволит избежать ошибок из-за несогласованности сборки в одной папке но с разным раcположением корневого CMakeLists.txt

Как вариант, можно добавить еще один cmake верхнего уровня и два этих включать в него. Однако работа с древовидно организованными проектами в CMake реализована тоже не ахти.